# Separar texto em linhas

Tags: r, texto

**Tenho uma variável de nome ESTADO onde as respostas estão inseridas assim:**

```
IDENTIFICADOR   ESTADO
1               MG / SP
2               RJ / BA
```

**Preciso ajustar para:**

```
IDENTIFICADOR   ESTADO
1                   MG
1                   SP
2                   RJ
2                   BA
```

Comment: O que está acontecendo? O que você realmente espera que aconteça?

Comment: Para mim está bem claro o que ele quer. Só separar uma lista em uma coluna em linhas, Usando o `tidyr` é só fazer `df <- separate_rows(df, ESTADO)`. Qualquer coisa olha aqui um exemplo completo: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_rows.html

Comment: Mas usando o tidyr ele manteria os identificadores ao separar a minha coluna estado?

Comment: df %>% 
  mutate(ESTADO=strsplit(ESTADO, "/")) %>% 
  unnest(ESTADO) CONSEGUI!!!!!